# Best practices with CMake with non-standard include and library directories

Tags: cmake

I have been trying to build Mozilla RR on a Linux box at work using CMake. We have a slightly eccentric arrangement where shared libraries are stored on network drives in locations like `/sw/external/product-name/linux64_g63.dll/`. Further, I have built some dependencies for the project in `$HOME/sw/`. (I am not a sudoer on this box.)

I am rather baffled as how I am supposed to communicate to CMake to look in non-standard directories. So far I have fudged:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$HOME/sw/capnproto-0.6.1/lib/pkconfig \
 CC=gcc-6.3 CXX=g++-6.3 \
 cmake \ 
 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/sw/rr-5.1.0 \
 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=$HOME/bin/python2 \
 -DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=$HOME/sw/libseccomp-2.2.3/ \
 ../src/
```

Which is obviously not a scalable solution, but it does at least complete the configuration successfully and emit some Makefiles.

If I omit `-DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=$HOME/sw/libseccomp-2.2.3/`, CMake fails, complaining about a missing libseccomp-2.2.3 dependency. But it works if I do have that definition, telling me that CMake understands where the libseccomp-2.2.3 files are and so will properly add the paths to the necessary compiler invocations.

However, `make` does not succeed, because `gcc` fails to find a required header file from the libseccomp probject. Examining `make VERBOSE=1`, I find that CMake hasn't added `-I$HOME/sw/libseccomp-2.2.3/include` to the `gcc` invocation.

---

I feel like this is not the right approach. The other answers I have looked at tell me to modify the CMakeLists.txt file, but surely

1. that is not going to be scalable across multiple CMake projects, and
2. for each project, that will need me to maintain a separate CMakeLists.txt file for every platform (Solaris/Linux/Darwin/Cygwin) I build the software on.

Is there a canonical solution to solving this problem? Perhaps a per-site configuration file that will tell CMake how to find libraries and headers, for all projects I build on that site?

Comment: `cmake` part succeeded and `make` part failed - this smells like the project's `CMakeLists.txt` has been written incorrectly. With `-D` parameters you may only hint the project **where to find** some things, like headers and libraries. But it is the project itself (its `CMakeLists.txt`) should use these hints. CMake doesn't pass them to the compiler automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is correct, but cmake is never told to include SECCOMP - see end of this post.

The way cmake can be informed about custom dependency directory depends on how the dependency is searched (i.e. on what is written in CMakeLists.txt).

### find_package/find_library/find_path/find_program

If dependency is found with one of above-mentioned commands, custom search directories can be easily added with [CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html). There is no need to add full path to include, lib or bin - when package root is added *find_*-command will check appropriate sub-directories. CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH can be also set with environment variable.

Second option is [CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH.html). Every path added to *CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH* list treated as separate root directory and is searched before system root directory. 
Note that *CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH* will be ignored by *find_*-commands with *NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH* argument.

Following four variables may be used to tune the usage of *CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH*:

- [CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE.html)
- [CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE.html)
- [CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY.html)
- [CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM.html)

When use of host system default libraries is undesired setting *CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE* and *CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY* to *ONLY* is a good practice. If dependency library or header is not found in *CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH* the configuration will fail. If cmake is allowed search system paths too, it is most likely that errors will occur during linking step or even runtime.

See [find_package](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) docs for more details.

### find_package only

All above applies to *find_package* command too.

*find_package* can operate in two modes *MODULE* and *CONFIG*.

In *MODULE* mode cmake uses Find[PackageName].cmake script (module) to find dependent package. CMake comes with large number of modules and custom modules can be added with *CMAKE_MODULE_PATH* variable. Often find-modules can be informed about custom search paths via environment or cmake variables.
E.g. *FindGTest.cmake* searches path stored in *GTEST_ROOT* variable.

If no find module is available, *find_package* enters *CONFIG* mode. If a dependency package provides [PackageName]Config.cmake or [LowercasePackageName]-config.cmake cmake can be easily informed about that package with [PackageName]_DIR variable.
Example:
CMakeLists.txt contains:

```
find_package(Qt5)
```

FindQt5.cmake is not available, but ~/Qt5/Qt5.8/lib/cmake/Qt5Config.cmake file exists, so add

```
-DQt5_DIR="${HOME}/Qt5/Qt5.8/lib/cmake"
```

to cmake call.

### pkg-config

CMake can use information provided by external pkg-config tool. It is usually done with *pkg_check_modules* command. Directory used by pkg-config can be customized with *PKG_CONFIG_PATH* environment variable. According to [cmake documentation](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html#variable:PKG_CONFIG_USE_CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH) instead of setting *PKG_CONFIG_PATH*, custom .pc-files directories can be added via *CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH*. If CMake version is pre-3.1, *PKG_CONFIG_USE_CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH* have to be set to *TRUE*(*ON*) to enable this feature.

Methods of customizing dependencies search path is defined by CMakeLists.txt content. There is no universal solution here.

**And now back to missing SECCOMP headers...**

In CMakeLists.txt SECCOMP header is found with

```
find_path(SECCOMP NAMES "linux/seccomp.h")
```

but I cannot find any command telling CMake to use the found header. For example:

```
target_include_directories(<target_name> ${SECCOMP})
```

or globally:

```
include_directories(${SECCOMP})
```

I belive that CMakeLists.txt should be fixed. It is not a platform dependent solution.

Comment: Variable [CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH.html) is used mostly for **cross-compiling**. Why do you suggest to use it here? For specifying install preficies of the programs, one may use variable [CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html) and its "friends".

Comment: @Tsyvarev You are right. I forgot about that application of CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. It definitely should be added to the answer.  I tend to use CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH because of "CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODES".

Comment: Message in [link](http://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake-developers/2012-January/014583.html) suggests that main difference between CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH and CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is list of sub-directories searched i.e. the first searches more sub-directories. Are there any other differences? I think it is a good candidate for a separate question.

Comment: The link explains, that in the case of *CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH* `the assumption is that under those prefixes a whole normal filesystem is 
located.`. This is much more (and different!) than simple installation prefix which is provided by *CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH*. But I agree that Stack Overflow's comments are not suitable for such explanations.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Answer improved. Thanks for comments.